# How to store blood glucose level in Microsoft HealthVault using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, healthvault

I am creating a web service to enter blood glucose levels into [Microsoft HealthVault](http://www.healthvault.com/personal/index.aspx). Anybody can use this web service along with their application to store the blood glucose level.

What do I need to do to implement this?

Comment: Which health vault? Is it a web service, a database, or something else? And what's particular about blood glucose level - isn't it just a number?

Comment: @Rup I think he means this: http://www.healthvault.com/personal/index.aspx

Comment: You will find everything you need here in the official site:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/healthvault/default

Comment: Health vault is a microsoft application. i am creating a web service to enter the blood glucose level to the health vault site. Anybody can use this webservice along with their application to store the blood glucose level.

Answer (score 0):

In order to develop for HealthVault platform, you will need to:

1. Download the SDK from MS site
2. Create new application using HealthVault application manager
3. You can configure application using Microsoft ACC (application configuration center) from HealthVault. There you can specify the "ThingTypes" you application will need to access (such as blood glucose).
4. SDK provides a few samples.